# Member <> is not recognized or is not accessible, while F12 brings me to the definition

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, uwp

To get a head start on a new UWP project, I copy a sample (NavigationMenu from https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples.git) into my own project, learning in the same time.

I am being very careful, and everything looks OK. But I get the above error a few times, while I can jump to the unrecognized member with F12 or actually have intellisense finding that member while typing in XAML.

I am at a lost about what to do to solve this, as I don't see what to "fix".
Is there any way to "debug" XAML in design time?

Thanks for your help!

Bernard

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

The least that I can say is that the errors triggered had **NOTHING** to do with the real cause!

For whatever reason, I opened the project in Blend. There I saw that I had inadvertently created a click event on a list item (in XAML), so it was not handled in code behind. I just deleted that click event, and everything finally compiled!

Lost quite a bunch of time chasing for false errors in Visual Studio...

If it may help someone else.....